# unable to create new launcher

Tags: 11.04, launcher

I cannot create a new launcher anywhere (either in the normal GNOME desktop or Unity).

No action when I right-click the desktop and select `Create Launcher...`.

At last I tried to create launcher, and I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/alacarte/Alacarte/MainWindow.py", line 312, in on_new_item_button_clicked
    process = subprocess.Popen(['gnome-desktop-item-edit', file_path], env=os.environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1213, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] Directory or file does not exist.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I discovered what was the problem. `sudo apt-get install gnome-panel` helped, now it is O.K.

Answer (score 2):

As you yourself stated in a comment, the solution is to install `gnome-panel`

`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel` should do the trick.

Comment: Importantly, if you're trying to do this in a minimal system on a lightweight Ubuntu derivative, like Lubuntu, you'll have to prevent recommended packages from being installed... sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends gnome-panel ...else you'll end up installing most of Ubuntu Desktop too.