# How to get the "new launcher"-wizard back into my context-menu?

Tags: nautilus

I wanted to create a new launcher, but when rightclick and new file, it says that there are no templates.

In [unable to create new launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55971/unable-to-create-new-launcher) was mentioned, that it should help to install gnome-panel. This package was already installed, so I removed it and all of it dependencies inclusive their settings and reinstalled. But nothing helped. There are no templates and I cant create a new launcher with a rightclick on my desktop.

But I like to use the "new launcher"-wizard I was used from 11.04 and before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nautilus script for that. Here are the commands:

```
wget  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47950494/Create-Launcher
cp Create-Launcher ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts
chmod +x ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/Create-Launcher
mv ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/Create-Launcher 'home/[your user name here]/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/Create Launcher'
```

The fourth command is just to rename the file, you can do that in Nautilus as well. Enjoy!

Source: [here](http://shuffleos.com/3708/how-to-create-desktop-launchers-right-click-context-menu-ubuntu-11-10/)

Comment: Alacarte seems only to affect the menu, but I want to do a right click on the desktop -> new file -> create launcher. I did that last time before updating to 11.10. I dont know if the contextmenu-entry was removed with that dist-upgrade or any later action I did to my system, but I want my create launcher wizard back, that one I was used to in 11.04 and before... I will modify the question a bit...

Comment: Your launchers created in Alacarte are stored in ~/.local/share/applications. You can copy them to desktop from there.

Comment: I want the old right-click behaviour back. It was there sometime and I just want it back without any workarounds!

Comment: @NobbZ enjoy the script. You could create it yourself by pasting the following in Gedit:
#!/bin/bash
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop

Comment: @NobbZ you also have the option of using Nautilus Actions. See: http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/12/how-to-add-create-launcher-action-for.html